# Valid Win 7 product key not working on pirate edition

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

I have a new EEE 1201ha, where I replaced the old disk with a SSD disk. It came with windows 7 Home Premium installed but no CD, and producing a recovery CD didn't help me. So I thought downloading the same edition as a torrent and using the valid key would be fine, but it obviously isn't as windows activation fails. How should I have done this correctly? What can I do now?

Regards
Haakon

Comment: Thanks for all the input, it put me on the right track. You can find an activation method by searching for "windows 7 loader", works fine for me and I don`t need to install windows again, which always is a bit time consuming. I don`t really care about "doing it right" when it comes to MS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what the right method would have been but if I had proof of purchase I'd have tried:

- contacting Asus
- contacting Microsoft
- going back to the place I bought it

As for recovery disks, when I bought my laptop, it was what they told me to do as well.

Pirated Windows *(if done right)* have always bypassed the Windows Activation Technology (aka Windows Genuine Advantage). In Windows 7, [a Windows Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971033) checks the status of the activation system and considers any circumnavigation of it as the piracy of Windows. Your serial key might be legit, but you're Windows isn't, since it's been exploited and compromised and you could have just as easily gotten away with fake key *(given you knew how to deal with the activation update)*.

Comment: + for input on WGA.

Answer (score 0):

The version pre-installed on computer isn't the same as a retail version, key-wise. It's why your key doesn't work. You would need the same oem version of windows for the key to work.

Most manufacturer will provide a CD/DVD image for their product at minimal cost (shipping cost habitually)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my ThinkPad. I just downloaded the OEM version (it's legal if you're for example in MSDNAA program, but I think it's not a problem since you have the key) and it didn't work the first time. I called Microsoft support and used the automated registration by phone and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, trusting a torrent or software made available in a manner that is not sanctioned by the manufacturer is a great way to get your identity stolen.

Second, I think you would have been better off asking a question about related to what happened when you tried to use the recovery CDs.

Third, You need to contact the maker of the computer and request media.  They almost certainly will charge you for it, but they shouldn't charge you the full cost of Windows.  I cannot say they MUST provide you the media, but I would expect they SHOULD.

Forth, if you replaced the hard drive, then put the old drive back.  Then image it and image it back to the new drive.  Logically, that should work.

Answer (score -1):

You should just phone Microsoft and explain to them the situation as long as you have proof the computer had Windows 7 on it (you'll need a receipt or something).

I wouldn't recommend anything else. Pirating should never be the answer. No matter how easy and happy it makes you. :D

Comment: The software is not pirated, he has a valid Serial Number.

Comment: Ehh, they still consider it pirating, even with the valid key.

Comment: Using a downloaded ISO and teaming it with a valid legit key is not pirating. You're paying for the license key, not for the media ( well, perhaps the disc & shipping cost).